# Why does my recursive function lead to: Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

**Question**

This problem takes its name by arguably the most important event in the life of the ancient historian Josephus: according to his tale, he and his 40 soldiers were trapped in a cave by the Romans during a siege.

Refusing to surrender to the enemy, they instead opted for mass suicide, with a twist: they formed a circle and proceeded to kill one man every three, until one last man was left (and that it was supposed to kill himself to end the act).

Well, Josephus and another man were the last two and, as we now know every detail of the story, you may have correctly guessed that they didn't exactly follow through the original idea.

You are now to create a function that returns a Josephus permutation, taking as parameters the initial array/list of items to be permuted as if they were in a circle and counted out every k places until none remained.

Tips and notes: it helps to start counting from 1 up to n, instead of the usual range 0..n-1; k will always be >=1.

For example, with n=7 and k=3 josephus(7,3) should act this way.

```js
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] - initial sequence
[1,2,4,5,6,7] => 3 is counted out and goes into the result [3]
[1,2,4,5,7] => 6 is counted out and goes into the result [3,6]
[1,4,5,7] => 2 is counted out and goes into the result [3,6,2]
[1,4,5] => 7 is counted out and goes into the result [3,6,2,7]
[1,4] => 5 is counted out and goes into the result [3,6,2,7,5]
[4] => 1 is counted out and goes into the result [3,6,2,7,5,1]
[] => 4 is counted out and goes into the result [3,6,2,7,5,1,4]
So our final result is:

josephus([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],3)==[3,6,2,7,5,1,4]
```

**Here is my solution**

```js
function josephus(items, k, a = [1]){
  let newArr = [];

  //when there is no array items left return the array 
  if(items.length == 1){
    newArr.push(items[0]);
    return newArr;
  }
  // recursive loop that keeps firing
  if((a[0] + k) > items.length){


    let surplus = items.length - (a[0] + k);
   a[0] = surplus;
    newArr.push(items[surplus]);
    
  } else {
    newArr.push(items[k + a[0]]);
    a[0] = items.indexOf((k + a[0]));

  }
 
  return josephus(items, k, a);
  
}


console.log(josephus([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],1));
console.log(josephus([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],2));
console.log((josephus(["C","o","d","e","W","a","r","s"],4)));
```

**There is one other problem**

If my solution is fixed then it will loop through as long as the count of people to skip is  lower than the total number of people x2 . But it would break if we needed to skip lets say six people but there were only 2 people in total. Therefore we need to fix this. I believe that the way to do this would be to build a recursive function inside the recursive function. How would you approach creating the internal recursive function?

*NB: the j in my code is to stop the browser crashing.*

Comment: Did you run through your code line-by-line in a debugger?

Comment: I don't know what that is?

Comment: A debugger is an essential tool in software development which allows you to run your program line by line and examine the values of variables while the program is being executed. You can reach the development tools of your web browser with F12. Regarding how to actually use the debugger of your web browser: That's a bit too much to explain in 500 characters, so I would recommend you to google it.

Comment: There's something wrong with the way you return the result. `newArr` is only ever returned in the first `if` (which should probably say ìf (items.Length() < k)` btw). Its only populated later, but not used any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues:

- `newArr` is never used after you have pushed a value to it. The only time it serves a purporse is when you *return* it. But then you keep returning *that* array (with `return josephus(.....)`), backtracking all the way out of recursion, and so the initial caller gets that array as well, which still has only one value.
- Don't add `k` to array *contents* like `a[0] + k`. Imagine `a[0]` is the "C" from the last example -- that cannot be right. You need to add it to an *index*, so you should provide an extra argument for the recursive call where you can specify that index. Also `a[0] = surplus` does not make sense for similar reasons. The resulting array would not have indexes, but the same contents as the input array in a different order.
- As you indicate, when the array is much shorter than `k`, you don't currently get to the right index. You can use the remainder `%` operator to get around that.

Although I don't see a reason to use recursion here, I will keep recursion in the proposed solution. You should however try to translate this to an iterative solution.

```js
function josephus(items, k, start = 0) { // Don't pass the result array, but the index
  if (items.length == 1) return items.slice(); // return a copy of the input array
  // don't add `k` to array contents, but to a given index (start)
  return items.splice(start, 1) // extract, and append rest of josephus permutation:
              .concat(josephus(items, k, (start + k-1) % items.length));
}

console.log(josephus([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],1));
console.log(josephus([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],2));
console.log((josephus(["C","o","d","e","W","a","r","s"],4)));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run your program in a debugger, then you will notice that the line `return  josephus(items, k, a);` is always exected with the same `items` array. The termination condition of your recursion is that the length of the array becomes 1, but that's not going to happen if you do not remove any elements from the array within your function.

Comment: I presumed that because I was pushing them, that they were leaving the original array

Comment: @AndrewNeedsHelp No, `push` only changes the array you call it on. It doesn't do anything with the source.